# Getting an undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am new to ROR and I can't seem to troubleshoot the following error message:

NoMethodError in GolfClubsController#show

undefined method `id' for #

Below are my models.

```
class GolfClub < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :course_nines
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 150 }
end

class CourseNine < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :golfclub_id
  belongs_to :golf_club
end
```

This is my controller:

```
def show
  @golf_club = GolfClub.find(params[:id])
  @courses = CourseNine.where(golfclub_id: @golf_club.id)
end
```

and my show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @golf_club.name) %>
<h1><%= @golf_club.name %></h1>

<% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <li>
    <%= course.name %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: sounds like it is not passing in a param. How did you get to this page?  What does your url look like?

Comment: I access the page by going to localhost:3000/golf_clubs/1

Comment: Do you have records in course_nines table?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 course_nines in that table with golfclub_id = 1. When I try it in the irb console, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the error is due to the way I named my fk. it should have been named golf_club_id in the CourseNine model instead of golfclub_id. It seems as if rails always looks for golf_club_id.

Comment: Glad you found it! feel free to accept your answer.